# Transistor as a switch

Tags: switches

I am having a tough time here.I want to design a simple transistor switch (obviously operating in saturation) using 2N3904.I want to switch a current of 10mA.
[image]

The part in yellow rectangle indicates if assuming saturation I use a base current of 1mA,I can get 10mA at the output.Then there is the part in red rectangle  where i have to find base current by Ic/hFE(min) (I am not even sure why this formula is used here because I am assuming saturation).But here Vce=1V which I don't think is well into saturation.There is a deep loop hole in my understanding somewhere,I know that.

Comment: hfe is irrelevant when the transistor is saturated. It will help you get there, but once you're there it doesn't matter all that much.

Comment: I knew that.But my textbook uses the procedure I have explained for red rectangle.Which one is right?

Comment: They're both right. The yellow box is for saturation, the red box is for active mode.

Comment: Not sure I understand where the question is. You want to find the base current, use the yellow box for base current (1mA) then use the Vbe (sat) for the maximum base voltage and you can find the resistor from the minimum input voltage. The hFE numbers are for operation outside of saturation.

Comment: Resistor from minimum input voltage?I am finding it from the value of base current i need.(Vin-Vbe)/Ib=Rb

Comment: Yes, (Vin_minimum - Vbe_maximum)/Ib = Rb, just to be clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the transistor to allow 10 mA to flow thru it C to E.  From the red box, you can see that the transistor has a gain of 100 at 10 mA.  That means 10mA / 100 = 100 µA is the minimum base current that just guarantees the transistor will conduct the current you want.

Since you are switching this current, not trying to control it proportionally, you should overdrive the transistor somewhat.  For switching like this, and considering the currents are low, I'd use a factor of two at least unless there are some other considerations you haven't mentioned.  That means you want to drive the base with at least 200 µA when switching on.

The yellow box only tells you how much inescapable C-E voltage drop the transistor will have even when driven fully on.  For example, if you are switching the ground to something connected to a 12 V supply, then that load will actually only see 11.8 V across it, not the full 12 V.  In most cases that's good enough, but you have to consider this to make sure.  If you're driving a LED, for example, there will be 200 mV less across the series resistor relative to a perfect switch, which in that case is easy to compensate for by making the resistor a little smaller.

The middle section tells you what the B-E drop will be, which is 850 mV max for 1 mA base current.  Since it doesn't say what it is at your base current, use that as your worst case too.  It's not going to be higher at lower base current.

Let's say you want to drive the transistor from a 3.3 V logic output.  You will need a resistor between the output and the base, with the emitter tied to ground.  Since the base can be as high as 850 mV, that leaves 2.45 V across the resistor.  (2.45 V)/(200 µA) = 12.25 kΩ, which is the maximum allowed base resistor to meet minimum base current we decided on earlier.  A little more base current won't hurt, so the common value of 10 kΩ will do nicely.

Depending on how fast the transistor needs to switch off, you may need to use a lower value or a C or R-C speedup circuit.  If you're just switching a indicator LED, just the 10 kΩ base resistor will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

The yellow box has 0.2 volts in the final column and this is likely to mean the collector-emiiter saturating voltage so, if you want to switch 10mA thru a load, drive the base with 1mA and expect the transistor to lose something like 0.2 volts.

Answer (score 0):

The red box is *not* used for saturation.

For saturation, you assume a value for hFE that is much smaller than the *actual* amplification, i.e., you use less collector current than you would be able to.
If IC is so high that it is limited by the transistor (the red box), you are *not* in saturation.

As you can see from the saturated values of IC/IB, hFE(SAT) is simply assumed to be 10.

Comment: But if I am working with yellow block,there is no need to calculate the hFE.I already have both the currents so I can proceed with finding the collector and the base resistances.Right?

Comment: But for a switch, you want to use saturation (otherwise, VCE is too large).

Comment: And I will set Vce=0.2.I am not getting what you are saying.I have spent like the entire day on this thing and couldn't find anything helpful.After finding hFE (as you are saying) what should be my next step then?